# What does _buildManifest.js in nextjs do, and can it be disabled?

Tags: next.js

We're building a site with NextJS, and noticed that in the source code of our website, we can find a `_buildManifest.js` file, which appears to list all pages currently defined on our site. We'd like this to not happen.

1. How is the `_buildManifest.js` file created, and what does it do?
2. How does it pull in the list of pages?
3. Is there a way disable its creation, and what breaks if we do?

Comment: Did you find a solution/answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We worked it out on our own, putting an update here.

1. It appears the build manifest is an autogenerated file that has a mapping of urls to the static JS chunk generated by webpack. This is primarily used for client-side navigation by the next/link component which, among other features, eagerly loads the JS on hover based on the href attribute.
2. The work is done by a webpack plugin defined [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/main/packages/next/build/webpack/plugins/build-manifest-plugin.ts), which grabs all urls and generated JS chunks from webpack and spits out a JSON file.
3. As of Next v10, overriding this webpack plugin and filtering the output through an allowlist seems to work; the only observed side effect is that clicking these links must be done through a normal `<a href>` instead of the next/link component, which disables client-side navigation. This may lead to slightly slower page navs (no eagerly loading client-side JS on hover) but does allow for hiding the urls from a publicly visible endpoint.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code?